# Async and await are single threaded really?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task

I created following code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
       {
         Console.WriteLine("M Start");
         MyMethodAsync();
         Console.WriteLine("M end");
         Console.Read();
       }

     static async Task MyMethodAsync()
     {
        await Task.Yield();
        Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperationAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("M3");
        //and now we call await on the task 
        int result = await longRunningTask;
        //use the result 
        Console.WriteLine(result);
     }

       static async Task<int> LongRunningOperationAsync()  
      {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 1;
      }
  }
}
```

The OutPut:

```
M Start
M end
M3
1
```

Which is fine but when I look in the Thread profiler its shows this:
[image]
And then this:
[image]
And then this:
[image]

So it looks like I spawn threads, but the Microsoft documentation says:

From [Task asynchronous programming model - Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_Threads)

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be
> created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async
> method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current
> synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the
> method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a
> background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process
> that's just waiting for results to become available.

Am I missing or don't understanding something?
Thanks.

Comment: it uses exisitng threads from thread pool, not create one

Comment: That looks like a really nifty window in Visual Studio. Sorry for the off-topic question, but which versions support it?

Comment: Decorate your output with `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and you'll probably see that 3 threads are being used.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis The `Parallel Stacks` and `Task` views where both added to VS 2013 I think. They are both found under the `Debug -> Windows` dropdown menu.

Comment: @DinkarThakur, kinda related to your question but you may be interested in reading Stepen Cleary's blog post "[There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)". It goes in to some indepth looks at what is going on when you await a IO based request.

Comment: so we have two answers both correct and spot on. Which one to accept?? :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I explain [how `async` and `await` work with threads and contexts](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog. In summary, when `await` needs to wait for an asynchronous operation to complete, it will "pause" the current `async` method and (by default) capture a "context".

When the asynchronous operation completes, that "context" is used to resume the `async` method. This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`. In your case, the context ends up being the thread pool context, so the rest of the `async` method is sent to the thread pool. If you run the same code from the UI thread, the context would be the UI context, and all the `async` methods will resume on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created.

Yes. It moves the CPU bound or I/O bound work to other thread from the thread pool of the process so that it is not executed on UI thread or current synchronization context, it does not create a new thread which is what meant in the MSDN description.

Comment: but if all thread are being consumed then it will wait. Right?

Comment: This is just wrong.  Tasks are executed on the current synchronization context.  A different thread is used only if you use a threadpool-based synchronization context, otherwise everything is done on the main thread with a queue.  Read about "continuation-passing style", which is how async works underneath.