# Can this kind of concurrency problem be solved with async/await?

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await

I have a function like such:

```
static void AddResultsToDb(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    foreach (int number in numbers)
    {
        int result = ComputeResult(number); // This takes a long time, but is thread safe.
        AddResultToDb(number, result); // This is quick but not thread safe.
    }
}
```

I could solve this problem by using, for example, `Parallel.ForEach` to compute the results, and then use a regular `foreach` to add the results to the database.

However, for educational purposes, **I would like a solution that revolves around await/async**. But no matter how much I read about it, I cannot wrap my mind around it. If await/async is not applicable in this context, I would like to understand why.

Comment: Since the purposes are educational, could we assume that the two methods called are asynchronous (`ComputeResultAsync`, `AddResultToDbAsync`)? Because if they are not asynchronous, the educational value of this exercise would very small, if not negative. async/await is a technology intended to solve problems of asynchrony, not concurrency.

Answer (score 3):

The *async and await pattern* is not really suitable for your first method. It's well suited for *IO Bound workloads* to achieve scalability, or for frameworks that have UI's for responsiveness. It's less suited for raw *CPU workloads*.

However you could still get benefits from *parallel processing* because your first method is *expensive* and *thread safe*.

In the following example I used [Parallel LINQ (PLINQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq) for a fluent expression of the results without worrying about a *pre-sized array* / *concurrent collection* / *locking*, though you could use other *TPL* functionality, like `Parallel.For/ForEach`

```
// Potentially break up the workloads in parallel
// return the number and result in a ValueTuple
var results = numbers.AsParallel()
                     .Select(x => (number: x, result: ComputeResult(x)))
                     .ToList();

// iterate through the number and results and execute them serially 
foreach (var (number, result) in results)
   AddResultToDb(number, result);
```

<sub>***Note** : The assumption here is the order is not important*</sub>

---

**Supplemental**

Your method `AddResultToDb` looks like it's just inserting results into a *database*, which is *IO Bound* and is worthy of `async`, furthermore could probably take all results at once and insert them in *bulk/batch* saving *round trips*

---

**From Comments** credit [@TheodorZoulias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11178549/theodor-zoulias)

> To [preserve the order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/order-preservation-in-plinq) you could use the method [AsOrdered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered?view=netframework-4.8), at
> the cost of some performance penalty. A possible performance
> improvement is to remove the `ToList()`, so that the results are added
> to the DB concurrently with the computations.

> To make the results available as fast as possible it's probably a good
> idea to disable the partial buffering that [happens by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelmergeoptions#fields), by
> chaining the method
> `.WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)` in the query

```
var results = numbers.AsParallel()
                     .Select(x => (number: x, result: ComputeResult(x)))
                     .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
                     .AsOrdered();
```

**Example**

---

**Additional resources**

[ParallelEnumerable.AsOrdered Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered?view=netframework-4.8)

> Enables treatment of a data source as if it were ordered, overriding
> the default of unordered. `AsOrdered` may only be invoked on non-generic
> sequences

[ParallelEnumerable.WithMergeOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withmergeoptions?view=netframework-4.8)

> Sets the merge options for this query, which specify how the query
> will buffer output.

[ParallelMergeOptions Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelmergeoptions?view=netframework-4.8)

> **NotBuffered**        Use a merge without output buffers. As soon as result elements have been computed, make that element available to the
> consumer of the query.

Comment: To [preserve the order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/order-preservation-in-plinq) you could use the method [`AsOrdered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered), at the cost of some performance deterioration. A possible performance improvement is to remove the `ToList()`, so that the results are added to the DB concurrently with the computations.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias hah stop stalking me! oh the picture is the same

Comment: You are making it too easy ! One more detail, associated with removing `ToList`. To make the results available as fast as possible it's probably a good idea to disable the partial buffering [that happens by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelmergeoptions#fields), by chaining the method `.WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)` in the query.

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested, this isn't a case of using `async`/`await` as that is for asynchrony. What you're doing is concurrency. Microsoft has a framework specifically for that and it solves this problem nicely.

So for learning purposes, you should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
static void AddResultsToDb(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    numbers 
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(n => Observable.Start(() => new { n, r = ComputeResult(n) }))
        .Do(x => AddResultToDb(x.n, x.r))
        .Wait();
}
```

The `SelectMany`/`Observable.Start` combination allows as many `ComputeResult` calls to occur as possible concurrently. The nice thing about Rx is that it then serializes the results so that only one call at a time goes to `AddResultToDb`.

---

To control the degrees of parallelism you can change the `SelectMany` to a `Select`/`Merge` like this:

```
static void AddResultsToDb(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    numbers 
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(n => Observable.Start(() => new { n, r = ComputeResult(n) }))
        .Merge(maxConcurrent: 2)
        .Do(x => AddResultToDb(x.n, x.r))
        .Wait();
}
```

Comment: RX has entered the chat... nice

Comment: The problem of this method, leaving aside the elephant in the room (the huge learning curve of the quite bulky and intricate [RX.Net](http://reactivex.io/) library), is that it's neither blocking nor asynchronous. You have no way to wait until the results are added to DB. In that aspect it resembles a fire-and-forget `Task`. And fixing this problem is not trivial.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - It's quite trivial. Change `.Subscribe(x => AddResultToDb(x.n, x.r))` to `.Do(x => AddResultToDb(x.n, x.r)).Wait()`.

Comment: Nice! I revoked my downvote. Is it possible to control the degree of parallelism of the computations, and also to save the results in the initial order?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I've added the code to change the degree of parallelism. To save in the original order (which the OP didn't ask for mind you) then you can use a `.Select((x, n) => ` at the beginning to record the order of the items and then use a call to `ToArray()` before the `Do` and then sort the all of the elements before expanding back out with a `SelectMany`.

Comment: The concurrency control doesn't seem to work. Whatever value I give to `maxConcurrent`, 4 `ComputeResult` are always running concurrently in my quad-core PC.

Comment: Also I am afraid that sorting the results by index will delay saving them to the database until all computations have been completed. Which is currently not the case (the results are saved concurrently with the computations, which is nice).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, there is a delay. I did have an operator I wrote that output items in the correct order - it queued up items that were out of order until the proceeding items were produced. I'll think about how to write that one again.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I'm not sure what's not working with the max degree of parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a case for `async/await` because it sounds like `ComputeResult` is expensive computationally, as opposed to just taking a long, indeterminate amount of time. `aync/await` is better for tasks you are truly waiting on. `Parallel.ForEach` will actually thread your workload.

If anything, `AddResultToDb` is what you would want to async/await - you would be waiting on an external action to complete.

Good in-depth explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35485780/127257

Answer (score -2):

Using `Parallel.For` honestly seems like the simplest solution, since your computations are likely to be CPU-bound. Async/await is better for I/O bound operations since it does not require another thread to wait for an I/O operation to complete (see [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)).

That being said, you can still use async/await for tasks that you put on the thread pool. So here's how you could do it.

```
static void AddResultToDb(int number)
{
    int result = ComputeResult(number); 
    AddResultToDb(number, result); 
}

static async Task AddResultsToDb(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    var tasks = numbers.Select
    (
        number => Task.Run( () => AddResultToDb(number) )  
    )
    .ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: should be `await AddResultToDb(number, result)`i guess. but also if `AddResultToDb` isn't thread safe would this be wise? or am i missing something pre morning coffee

Comment: @MichaelRandall You're right, either I need to add an `await` or remove the `async Task` from `AddResultToDb()`. I assume these operations are thread-safe since OP is asking about alternatives to `Parallel.For`.

Comment: @JohnWu - The OP explicitly said that `AddResultToDb` was not thread-safe.